# Can custom attributed be added to anchor tags?

Tags: html, attributes, anchor

Can custom attributes be added to anchor tags? Example:

```
<a href="#" custom-attr="value1" custom-attr2="value2"> Link </a>
```

Are there any compatibility/performance concerns between different browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for that.

Like:

```
<a href="#" data-foo="value1" data-bar="value2">Link</a>
```